# Use of -1 to express edge cases in computer programs and data structures

Tags: data-structures, integers

Often I will encounter the use of - or even use myself - the value **`-1`** as an edge case in otherwise integer data structures. For instance, as the value for "irreplaceable" in a *Replacement Cost* field.

This is especially useful where **`null`** is either unrecognised; semantically overburdened; or converted into **`empty`** when migrating data across formats.

***What is the formal computer science view on the use of negative integers for non-numeral meanings in data fields which are still used normally for positive integers?***

Comment: This is a question about programming, not about computer science.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I initially thought that; until I realised I know full well how to code edge cases; but not whether (given the CompSci origins of robust programming), when or if it is appropriate to use -1 or similar in this fashion. For example, a question about GOTO usage starts as, and returns to, a Computer Science foundation.

Answer (score 2):

Most PL folks would probably suggest that an [option type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) is better suited.

For instance, in Haskell you'd use a `Maybe T` type: you use `Nothing` instead of `-1`, and `Just x` instead of `x`.  In SML, you'd use a `T option` type, and use `None` instead of `-1` and `SOME x` instead of `x`.

The benefit of this is to better document the meaning of the sentinel value, and also to force the programmer to consider both cases everywhere it is relevant.  This helps avoid certain kinds of programming mistakes, where a `-1` value is inadvertently used as if it were a real value.  It also ensures that the domain of the type `T` is separate from the sentinel value.

In a language without an option type, you can also use tagged unions or other methods of encoding this into the type system or class hierarchy.

That said, this is a pretty subjective question.  Opinions will vary.  You should not expect everyone in a field to share the same opinion about a subjective matter like this.